# django.contrib.auth.views LoginView and LogoutView not working

Tags: python, django

I am using latest version of django and I want to create a login-logout page using builtin system. But this is giving error when I try to run the server.

[image: This is the image of all the errors shown]

Below is the urls.py code.

from django.contrib import admin

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog_app.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html')),
    path('accounts/logout/',views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),
]
```

Below is the blog_app/urls.py code

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog_app import views

URL_PATTERNS = [
    url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='new_post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.UpdatePostView.as_view(),name='edit_post'),
    url(r'^drafts/$', views.DraftListView.as_view(),name='draft_post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.DeletePostView.as_view(),name='delete_post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
]
```

Below is the login.html code

```
{% extends 'blog_app/base.html' %}

{%block body_block%}
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>PLEASE LOGIN:</h2>
    {% if forms.errors %}
      <p>Username and Password didn't match. Please try again!</p>
    {%endif%}

    <form method="POST" action="{%url 'login' %}">
      {%csrf_token%}
        {{form.as_p}}

        <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Login">
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
    </form>
  </div>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: do you have any urls in `'blog_app.urls'`? if yes please add the urls of 'blog_app.urls' as well

Comment: You've got `URL_PATTERNS = ` instead of `urlpatterns = ` in `blog_app.urls`. Voting to close since this is just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **blog_app/urls.py** code

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from blog_app import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
        url(r'^about/$', views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
        url(r'^post/new/$', views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='new_post'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.UpdatePostView.as_view(),name='edit_post'),
        url(r'^drafts/$', views.DraftListView.as_view(),name='draft_post_list'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.DeletePostView.as_view(),name='delete_post'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
        url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
        url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
    ]
```